# What is causing lag in this simple game?

Tags: python, pygame, refresh, lag

I have this classic example of a pygame program:

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the ball.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'Group.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# This is a list of every sprite. 
# All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(100):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Create a RED player block
player = Block(RED, 20, 15)
all_sprites_list.add(player)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
    # as a list of two numbers.
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Fetch the x and y out of the list,
       # just like we'd fetch letters out of a string.
    # Set the player object to the mouse location
    player.rect.x = pos[0]
    player.rect.y = pos[1]

    # See if the player block has collided with anything.
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    # Check the list of collisions.
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score += 1
        print(score)

    # Draw all the spites
    for block in all_sprites_list:
        if block.rect.y + 1 > screen_height:
            block.rect.y = 0
        block.rect.y = block.rect.y + 1
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(120)

pygame.quit()
```

Well, I notice that when I move the mouse, the rest of the blocks are moving slower(like freezing for a fraction of the second) but when it is in one place everything is moving smooth. The player sprite is in the list of all sprites and there is no calculation of the position of the player - only getting mouse's coordinates. And in my opinion there shouldn't be difference between getting (100,100) all the time and getting something else for coordinates of the mouse.

Could someone please explain why motion of the mouse (player's sprite) affects the rest of the sprites?
Thanks!

Comment: It could be the `print` statement. Try running your game with the `print(score)` commented out and `clock.tick(200)`. I have noticed that printing out to the console instead of displaying it in the game screen often is a source of lag.

Comment: I've just tried - it's not from the print statement :( And if I increase the clock.tick the lag becomes more visible.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your observations. In fact, with the print commented out and increasing `clock.tick`, I get a smoother and lag-free game.  ; For me, it doesn't make a difference whether the mouse is stationary or moving.

Comment: Seriously? Well, that's strange. I mean I run it on a reasonably good machine (i7, 8GB ram, 2GB video). Are you sure you don't notice the little lag spike while fast moving the mouse?

Comment: None at all if I comment out the `print`. There is some lag with the `print` though and it gradually decreases as the number of blocks left reduce. But there is **no difference** in the lag if the mouse is stationary or moving in either case. My specs are the same except for a 4GB ram.

Comment: Well, it turned out that I just had to restart my computer. Everything is running smooth now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you've been running Python for too long a while without restarting, and a fair bit of data has [accumulated in memory without being deallocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) during previous runs. As noted in the comments, rebooting will usually solve it.

Comment: I know the problem has been resolved already and some months ago, but I thought I would post this to give it proper closure.